# How to avoid recompilation of numba code when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, numba

I am new to numba, and I found that numba function is very fast when using signle processing (numpy 0.20s and numba 0.04s for running 1000 times), but it is very **slow when using multi processing under jit**, and it is not working **under aot**. I have tried nogil, cache, parallel and etc. My numpy or numba function is cpu intensive, so I **cannot use thread or prange**.

base.py

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from numba.pycc import CC


cc = CC("my_numba")


class MathHelper:
    @staticmethod
    def np_ffill(arr: np.array):
        mask = np.isnan(arr)
        if arr.ndim == 1:
            idx = np.where(~mask, np.arange(mask.size), 0)
            np.maximum.accumulate(idx, out=idx)
            return arr[idx]
    @staticmethod
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def nb_ffill_jit_v1(arr: np.array):
        values = arr.copy()
        if arr.ndim == 1:
            last_value = np.nan
            for n in range(arr.size):
                if np.isnan(arr[n]):
                    values[n] = last_value
                else:
                    last_value = arr[n]
        return values
    @staticmethod
    @jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
    def nb_ffill_jit_v2(arr: np.array):
        ...  # (copy nb_ffill_jit_v1 code to here)
    @staticmethod
    @jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=True)
    def nb_ffill_jit_v3(arr: np.array):
        ...
    @staticmethod
    @cc.export("nb_ffill_aot_v1", "f8[:](f8[:])")
    def nb_ffill_aot_v1(arr: np.array):
        ...
    @staticmethod
    @jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
    @cc.export("nb_ffill_aot_v2", "f8[:](f8[:])")
    def nb_ffill_aot_v2(arr: np.array):
        ...
    @staticmethod
    @jit(nopython=True, parallel=True, nogil=True)
    @cc.export("nb_ffill_aot_v3", "f8[:](f8[:])")
    def nb_ffill_aot_v3(arr: np.array):
        ...
    @staticmethod
    @jit(nopython=True, parallel=True, nogil=True, cache=True)
    @cc.export("nb_ffill_aot_v4", "f8[:](f8[:])")
    def nb_ffill_aot_v4(arr: np.array):
        ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

numba_test.py

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
from typing import Union

import numpy as np

import my_numba
from base import MathHelper


def np_arr(n: int, low: Union[int, float] = 1000, high: Union[int, float] = 2000, digit: int = 0):
    return np.around(np.random.rand(n) * (high - low) + low, digit)

def np_arr_nan(n: int, n_nan: int, low: Union[int, float] = 1000, high: Union[int, float] = 2000, digit: int = 0):
    idx = np.random.choice(n, n_nan, replace=False)
    arr = np_arr(n, low, high, digit)
    arr[idx] = np.nan
    return arr

def multi_timeit(func, *args):
    time_start = time.time()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
        for _ in range(25):
            executor.submit(func, args)
    return time.time() - time_start

def single_timeit(func, *args):
    time_start = time.time()
    for _ in range(1000):
        func(*args)
    return time.time() - time_start

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr_nan_small = np_arr_nan(40000, 1000, digit=2)
    
    MathHelper.nb_ffill_jit_v1(arr_nan_small)
    print(single_timeit(MathHelper.np_ffill, arr_nan_small))
    print(single_timeit(MathHelper.nb_ffill_jit_v1, arr_nan_small))

    print(multi_timeit(MathHelper.np_ffill, arr_nan_small))
    print(multi_timeit(MathHelper.nb_ffill_jit_v1, arr_nan_small))
    print(multi_timeit(MathHelper.nb_ffill_jit_v2, arr_nan_small))
    print(multi_timeit(MathHelper.nb_ffill_jit_v3, arr_nan_small))
    print(multi_timeit(MathHelper.nb_ffill_aot_v1, arr_nan_small))
    print(multi_timeit(MathHelper.nb_ffill_aot_v2, arr_nan_small))
    print(multi_timeit(MathHelper.nb_ffill_aot_v3, arr_nan_small))
    print(multi_timeit(MathHelper.nb_ffill_aot_v4, arr_nan_small))
    print(multi_timeit(my_numba.nb_ffill_aot_v1, arr_nan_small))  # not working
    print(multi_timeit(my_numba.nb_ffill_aot_v2, arr_nan_small))  # not working
    print(multi_timeit(my_numba.nb_ffill_aot_v3, arr_nan_small))  # not working
    print(multi_timeit(my_numba.nb_ffill_aot_v4, arr_nan_small))  # not working
```

Comment: I am not sure this works for with staticmethod but you can provide a Numba signature to `nb_ffill_jit_v1` so Numba should compile the function ahead of time. Things tends to be significantly more complex when you mix Numba with classes from my past experiences.